# How to add array type parameters in a function C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I am starting with a project in **ASP.Net** and I have a function to perform a login which has `userId` and `password` as parameters,  but I need to make an array of these parameters, since this will allow me to use different ones `userId` with their respective `password`, function that i am using is as follows:

```
public string Login(string sessionTicket, string dataSource, string userId, string password, int features) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("Login", new object[] {
                        sessionTicket,
                        dataSource,
                        userId,
                        password,
                        features});
            return ((string)(results[0]));
        }
```

In addition to the above, I will use this function in the following method, which I will also have to convert the parameters `xtUser` and `xtPass` an array:

```
string sessionTicket = axServicesInterface.Login("",
            GlobalVariables.dataSource,GlobalVariables.xtUser, GlobalVariables.xtPass,
            Convert.ToInt32(EAxType.AxFeature_Basic));
```

Attached image of the parameters that the login function has:

[image]

The login array is required to be able to alternate the two users that I have each requests

**UPDATE:**

Try the answer thing but I have an error saying "userID does not exist in context"

```
public class LoginDetails
        {
            public string userId { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set }
        }

        public string Login(string sessionTicket, string dataSource, LoginDetails[] loginDetails, int features) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("Login", new object[] {
                        sessionTicket,
                        dataSource,
                        userId,
                        password,
                        features});
            return ((string)(results[0]));
        }
```

[image]

They know if what I am doing is correct for what I need, this is how I can solve the current error.

Comment: The method you are Invoking in your update most likely expects on set of `userId` and `password`. Iterate the new array that you have calling Invoke for each item in your array.

Comment: I suspect you will want to `foreach` over `loginDetails`.

Comment: @JonP Can you explain it better

Comment: @SebastianSalazar you are now passing a LoginDetails array (I assume it's filled?) to the "outer" method, but never using it inside it.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing  I need to fill the array with user1 and password 1234, how can I do it?

Comment: Your questions isn't quite clear: do you want to login with multiple sets of usernames and passwords? Why use Invoke at all? If a method expects to be called with a string parameter, you cannot just pass an array and expect it to be executed for every value in the array

Comment: @HansKeﬆing That's right I need to login with multiple sets of username and passwords, at least two

Comment: Then call that deeper login method multiple times, once for each set. Then you need to figure out what to return as "combined answer"

Comment: @JonP I use "Invoke" to invoke an XML Web service method synchronously using SOAP

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 
You can add it to an answer to take it as an example and thus validate your answer

Comment: Invoke is a VERY old way of calling a web service, there are many better ways of doing that in .net these days. I haven't used invoke since 1.1 . Google is your friend  here

Comment: @JonP 
I require using "invoke" because I am using ApplicationXtender Web Services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the following class (to allow you to have multiple sets of username and password):

```
public class LoginDetails {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set }
}
```

Then rather than passing `string userId, string password`, pass `LoginDetails[] loginDetails` as the parameter.